# How to input new line string using java-util-scanner in this situation?

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer

I'm trying to create a simple String Calculator that allows an Add() method to handle new lines between numbers (instead of commas)-

- The following input is ok: “1\n2,3” (will equal 6)
- The following input is NOT ok: “1,\n”

How am I supposed to *input string with nextline(\n) in it* and split or tokenize on the basis of both the "\n" and ","?

I have given the piece of my Add() method below which is able to return the sum of the tokens-

```
public static int Add(String numbers1) {
    int sum = 0;

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(numbers1, "\r?\n");

    while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    }
    return sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple idea: in your original input string replace all '\n' with ',' or other way around, and then you only have one delimiter. Also, note that StringTokenizer class is a legacy class, and it is recommended to use the method `String.split(...)` Regular expressions instead.

Comment: thanks but my assignment requires the Add() to be able to take an input such as “1\n2,3” and give sum 6. How do I input “1\n2,3”? Do I use Scanner?

Comment: The scanner will interpret the new line as a delimiter. If you want to use the scanner you will have to use its method useDelimeter to change your delimiter to something else